PBI Dax trying to produce a list of pickup locations within 50 miles of city, state lookup
I am trying to produce a list of nearby pickup locations in the US within a 50 mile radius of my city, state lookup value. I have pickup latitude and longitude in tableA and I have us cities lat and long listed in tableB. I have found formulas for measures using a fixed start location for a distance radius but I have not been able to find one that works with a dynamic start location. The start location for me being the city state lookup value.
I have tried this measure
`=
var Lat1 = MIN('tableB'[lat])
var Lng1 = MIN('tableB'[lng])
var Lat2 = MIN('tableA'[lat])
var Lng2 = MIN('tableA'[lng])

var P = DIVIDE( PI(), 180 )
var A = 0.5 - COS((Lat2-Lat1) * p)/2 + 
COS(Lat1 * p) * COS(lat2 * P) * (1-COS((Lng2- Lng1) * p))/2
var final = 12742 * ASIN((SQRT(A)))
return final`

This just returned a total not a distance for each location
I have tried this calculated column
= ACOS(SIN('tableA'[PICKUP_LAT]*PI()/180) * SIN('tableA'[DELIVERY_LAT]*PI()/180) + COS('tableA'[PICKUP_LAT]*PI()/180) * COS('tableA'[DELIVERY_LAT]*PI()/180) *COS('tableA'[DELIVERY_LON]*PI()/180-'tableA'[PICKUP_LON]*PI()/180)) * 3959
This is what I tried before having the thought that the start location should be based off a separate table.

Can you please provide some sample data, expected output, or a file so we may replicate this issue?

Here's a summary of the steps I recommend taking:

Add TableB[Location] to a slicer.
Create a measure to calculate distance.
Add measure to table and filter by less than or equal to 50 miles.

1. Create a table of only Locations to be used by slicer.

2. Create a measure to calculate distance.
HaversineDistance = 
    VAR __FromCity = SELECTEDVALUE(TableB[Location])
    VAR __FromLat = LOOKUPVALUE('TableB'[Latitude],'TableB'[Location],__FromCity)
    VAR __FromLong = LOOKUPVALUE('TableB'[Longitude],'TableB'[Location],__FromCity)
    
    VAR __ToCity = SELECTEDVALUE('TableA'[Location])
    VAR __ToLat = SELECTEDVALUE(TableA[Latitude])//LOOKUPVALUE('TableA'[Latitude],'TableA'[Location],__ToCity)
    VAR __ToLong = SELECTEDVALUE(TableA[Longitude])//LOOKUPVALUE('TableA'[Longitude],'TableA'[Location],__ToCity)

    VAR __distanceLong = RADIANS(__ToLong - __FromLong)
    VAR __distanceLat = RADIANS(__ToLat - __FromLat)

    VAR __a = (SIN(__distanceLat/2))^2 + COS(RADIANS(__FromLat)) * COS(RADIANS(__ToLat)) * SIN((__distanceLong/2))^2
    VAR __y = SQRT(__a)
    VAR __x = SQRT(1 - __a)
    VAR __atan2 = 
        SWITCH(
            TRUE(),
            __x > 0, ATAN(__y/__x),
            __x < 0 && __y >= 0, ATAN(__y/__x) + PI(),
            __x < 0 && __y < 0, ATAN(__y/__x) - PI(),
            __x = 0 && __y > 0, PI()/2,
            __x = 0 && __y < 0, PI()/2 * (0-1),
            BLANK()
        )
    VAR __c = 2 * __atan2
    
    VAR earthRadius = 3958.8  -- Earth's radius in miles; use 6371 for kilometers
RETURN
    __c * earthRadius

Source: link
3. Add measure to table and filter by less than or equal to 50 miles.


Mock Data:



Route
Location
Latitude
Longitude




1
New York, NY
40.7128
-74.0060


2
Philadelphia, PA
39.9526
-75.1652


3
Newark, NJ
40.7357
-74.1724


4
Stamford, CT
41.0534
-73.5387


5
Trenton, NJ
40.2171
-74.7429


6
Allentown, PA
40.6084
-75.4902


7
New Brunswick, NJ
40.4862
-74.4518


8
Yonkers, NY
40.9312
-73.8988


9
White Plains, NY
41.0330
-73.7629


10
Princeton, NJ
40.3573
-74.6672


11
Princeton, NJ
40.9312
-73.8988




Thanks for the swift answer. This makes sense, but the only issue that I am running into is my 'Table'[Location] has duplicate locations because there are multiple pickups in the same cities. This is producing a calculation error "'Measures Table'[HaversineDistance]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected." So I am working on an alternative to the LOOKUPVALUE function, but this is definitely a great starting point. @Nick

I've updated the process and code to align with using TableB as the FromCity for calculations

I still have "MdxScript(Model) (85, 31) Calculation error in measure 'Measures Table'[HaversineDistance]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected."
I think this is because there are multiple values in the 'TableA' locations, lat, and lng. @Nick

Oh, I understand now. I updated the measure to look at the specific lat and long from the table. If you do not plan on using the lat and long in the table, is there a unique identifier for each pickup location?

There is a unique route number for each pickup location. @nick

What is you exact expected result for your question? Is it a table? What columns are in the table?

The result I am trying to produce is someone will search a particular city, state and a table visual will populate with Route Number, Pickup Location, and the Distance from the search location.
There are duplicate pickup locations because they will have different delivery locations and an unique route number assigned to each one.

My answer above should work then. Just put the Route Number in the table and remove Lat and Long columns.

For some reason the Distance value is displaying 5,895.66 miles for every Pickup Location.

Can you please provide some sample data you are using so I can replicate? Also did you create a measure or column?
